# Create ggplot2 figure of two mirrored density curves with a line plot in the middle (or: recreate Drift Diffussion Model diagram in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Note: I use the term mirrored loosely, I just mean one density curve is inverted]

There are likely better ways to ask this question, but I would like to use ggplot2 to recreate this standard type of DDM (Drift Diffusion Model) plot:

[image]

The code I've developed below creates the two density curves, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I could create an space between the two curves to plot the drift (i.e. a point moving along a simulated diffusion process).

```
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, rdists)

rt1 <- rdiffusion(500, a=1, v=2, t0=0.5)
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data=subset(rt1, response=="upper"), aes(rt, fill="upper", y= ..count..)) +
  geom_rug(data=subset(rt1, response=="upper"), aes(rt, fill="upper"), sides = "tr") +
  geom_density(data=subset(rt1, response=="lower"), aes(rt, fill="lower", y= -..count..)) +
  geom_rug(data=subset(rt1, response=="lower"), aes(rt, fill="lower")) +
  scale_fill_hue("response")
```

This produces the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `patchwork`.

Dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <- tibble(
  x = c(sort(runif(50)), sort(runif(50))),
  y = c(cumsum(runif(50, -0.5)), cumsum(runif(50, -1.5))),
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50)
)
```

Create the 3 plots.

```
p_density_top <-
  df %>%
  filter(group == "A") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
    geom_density(fill = "purple") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      axis.title = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank()
    )

p_density_bottom <-
  df %>%
  filter(group == "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
    geom_density(fill = "red") +
    scale_y_reverse() +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank()
    )

p_middle <-
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = group)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "red")) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank()
    )
```

Use `patchwork` to display them together.

```
(p_density_top + p_middle + p_density_bottom) + plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 5, 1))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: slick! I feel silly for not having considered that. Thank you for such a comprehensive response.